# Ansible: Correct way of using variables in conditional 'when' checks

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

We use AWX/Tower to run our playbooks in a growing infrastructure and maintain a common inventory on AWX server itself using *smart inventory*.

This is the issue we have:

Out of 200+ servers, we only want a small subset to exclude a specific task. The current working way we have is where we define variables in a file such as,

```
http_conf_ignore:
   vmhost01: false
   vmhost02: false
```

and then in the yml file we have a conditional check as follow,

```
tasks:
  - include_tasks: http_config.yml
when: http_conf_ignore.{{ inventory_hostname }} is not defined
```

This works however we get a warning message saying **"When statement should not use jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} and {% %}"** and I'm not a fan of supressing warnings. Also, we wouldn't want to have multiple seperate inventories

Can someone suggest what are the best practices when using variables in this manner.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to the `when` directive is a Jinja conditional expression.  Because it's *already* interpreted as a Jinja expression, you don't need the `{{...}}` markers.  That's why you can reference a variable like `http_conf_ignore` outside of the markers.  The `inventory_hostname` variable isn't any different.  What you want is something like:

```
when: http_conf_ignore[inventory_hostname] is not defined
```

(If you were to write something like `http_conf_ignore.inventory_hostname`, you would be asking for the value of the literal key `inventory_hostname`. Using the `variable[key]` syntax, which resembles Python dictionary access, is how you dereference a dictionary using the value of the `key` variable.)

Incidentally, another way of approaching this would be to set an `http_conf_ignore` variable on specific hosts in your inventory.  E.g., in your inventory:

```
vmhost01 http_conf_ignore=true
```

This would allow your `when` condition to be:

```
when: not http_conf_ignore|default(false)
```